# Dynamics 365 Workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have a workflow that automatically updates a contact to a specific owner that matches the linked Company owner when a contact record is created. What I want to do is to send an email when an owner changes AFTER a contact record is created. Any idea how I include this in a workflow? At the moment the e-mail is triggering when the first workflow is running which  don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Create a two-option field on the contact called "Creation Completed" or something similar, On the Assign WF put in a conditional branch:

```
If Creation Completed = false
  Update Creation Completed = true
Else
  Send Email
```

This should prevent an email being sent when the first workflow reassigns the contact.

Comment: Thanks for this. Sorry I don'tt understand as all the records will be created?

Comment: Thanks @BillV. Good idea. Amanda, Yes, all records will be created. The idea here is to know whether the workflow is running on the Create or not. Putting this branching logic into the Assign workflow allows you to skip sending the email on the first assignment that runs right after the create, while allowing it to run on later assignments. As BillV points out, it requires a separate "flag" field.

Comment: Thanks @Aron. The option field on the contact form how would I update that?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a separate workflow that triggers when a Contact gets assigned:

[image: OnAssign]

To suppress the email for a period of time you could create a check condition to see if the Assign workflow is running more than X minutes after the CreatedOn time (in this case 15 minutes after).

[image: workflowCreatedOn]

Comment: Hi Aron yes I have this workflow but it is triggering when the owner is changing on creation (e the first workflow) and I only want an e-mail to be sent after this change.

Comment: A workflow that's set only to trigger on Assign should not trigger on Create. Creating a record triggers the Create message, not Assign. To confirm you can create a test workflow on an unused entity that triggers only on Assign. Is there perhaps another workflow that's assigning each Contact after it gets created? If so, you might have to do something that checks whether the CreatedOn dateTime is within 5 minutes or something like that.

Comment: Yes there is a workflow triggering after creation to assign some owners so this is also triggering the e-mail. I did add a

Comment: Yes there is a workflow triggering after creation to assign some owners so this is also triggering the e-mail. I did add an if 'contact created after 1 hour' but nothing is triggering now. Could you let me know specifically how I would create that workflow.